# Can I submit my old PhD thesis to arxiv with the date set to its original submission date?

Tags: publications, thesis, arxiv

I have completed my PhD 10 years ago, and back then I was not sure if it was ok with my home institution to have it in arxiv. I then realized it's fine and it would actually be good as my institution never cared to set up an open database of their own PhD theses. My question is: is there a way to post it on arxiv with the proper date, so that it shows on a search but it does not show among the most recent ones?

EDIT: given the popularity of the question, would it make sense to allow the ability to backdate ONLY PhD theses? It seems like my experience is a shared one, and I can't imagine anybody in her/his own mind lying on when she/he got her/his PhD.

Comment: Just stop worrying about the date. Seriously, people don't make much out of them. Say in the comments field that the thesis is from 10 years ago.

Comment: PS. Just as an example, it isn't unheard of that someone's theses get posted on the arXiv long after the fact: https://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Reinert_B/0/1/0/all/0/1 .

Comment: Last time I tried to upload a chapter from my thesis they told me it isn't publishable as a journal paper and I will get banned if I try that again.

Comment: @VladimirF Where, on arXiv?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Sure.

Comment: Have you considered other services? Or does it have to be arXiv? If not, you could use https://zenodo.org/ or https://www.authorea.com. Both I believe will even generate a DOI for your Thesis.

Comment: @VladimirF Well, a single chapter from a thesis is rarely a complete work in its own right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think so.

The "proper date" for an eprint *is* the date you upload it to the arxiv.  If the arxiv allowed people to back date their work (by up to ten years!), then it would at best confuse and at worst totally ruin the use of the arxiv to sort out chronology and claims of priority.  So while I don't *know* that they don't allow this, I have never seen an example, and I *hope* that they don't.

What you can do, of course, is to include in the comments that this is your thesis from 10 years ago.  If you do that then everything seems clear.  If you are worried that your thesis appearing on the feed/list of new papers will cause it to get more attention....wait, isn't that why you are posting it to the arxiv in the first place?

Comment: I believe the only times the arXiv has ever allowed backdating content is when it was part of a systematic migration from another widely used, public source.  For example, Thurston did not submit [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9404236) in 1994; rather, it was submitted on his behalf in 1999.  However, it was published in 1994.  I'm not aware of any recent cases in which even this has been allowed by the arXiv, and they definitely do not allow individual users to do it.

Comment: Re “appearing on the feed will cause it to get more attention… wait, isn’t that why you’re posting it to the arXiv in the first place?”  No, not necessarily at all!  I can’t speak for OP, but for me, I’ve considered posting my thesis to the arXiv for the sake of providing a long-term stable easily-accessible copy, but decided against it because I was reluctant to draw extra attention to something I now feel is both immature and outdated.

Comment: @PLL: While your position makes sense, it clearly expresses ambivalence about the prospect of others viewing your thesis work: in some sense you want this and in another sense you don't.  (You also want to ensure long-term access to something that you feel is outdated: more mixed feelings.)  Note that are other online respositories for PhD theses that make the theses much harder to get ahold of (institutional access or payment may be required).  The arxiv is for work that you want people to see.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: As you say, I’m a bit ambivalent.  I want people to be *able* to see it easily and freely if they are looking for it (e.g. following up references to it from other work), without payment or subscription required (there are obvious ethical reasons for this), but I don’t want to *advertise* it.  I think this is not an unusual or inconsistent position — and the arXiv is absolutely ideal for the things I do want, it’s just that the newsfeed also adds a little of what I don’t want.

Comment: @PLL I agree with you: the idea is precisely that I don't want to attract attention to a 10 year old piece of work. In my case the work was complete (and in fact published on a separate paper) still it is obsolete. The main reason why I would like to have it on arxiv is to allow easy access to anybody.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I agree with you that backdating articles will mess up the entire purpose of arxiv. However, it's a different story for PhD theses. Or would you like perhaps to see a different site taking care of PhD theses? Clearly I do not want attention to my very first piece of scientific work beyond its historical relevance in my subfield.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but you can contact the Arxiv people here:

https://arxiv.org/help/contact

(those are instructions and an email address, but do read the instructions as a courtesy.)

and ask them to add the feature of having two separate dates - the date of upload/submission to ArXiv and the original date the work was published/appeared on. That's not a bad idea IMHO.

Comment: You can already add the publication information of the preprint in the comments.  (Many people go back and add this when the paper is published; many don't.)  So I don't see why a new feature is really necessary.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark as per my comment above: I would not like to raise attention to an old piece of work. On the other hand, I do would like to have a chance to store my PhD in a publicly accessible place, the same way as my younger colleagues have done in more recent times. According to the number of upvotes, this feature seems like of popular interest!

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Because it's not just comment text, it's a structural field, and is often just as important as when you've uploaded your file.

Comment: I would be opposed to such a feature.  For published work, the journal reference field is already there for the full publication details, including the date.  For most unpublished work, the date it first appeared is not really a precise concept.  (Does it mean the first date you showed it to anyone?  The date you made the final edits?  The date you posted it to a previous website?)  Theses are one of the few cases that have a widely agreed upon date but that don't fit the journal reference field very well, and I don't think it's worth introducing a special field primarily for them.